# PHP: How to make an api call with api key authorization using Guzzle?

Tags: php, laravel, ibm-watson, guzzle, api-key

I'm trying to create a client to connect an IBM-Watson bot service using Guzzle for an application constructed in Laravel, but it fails when attempting to create a new session of the service, I got the error 401: Unauthorized. I'm not using basic authorization, instead I'm trying to connect by api-key authorization.

```
function start_bot_session() {

    //Api Key de Watson.
    $api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    //ID bot (Watson).
    $assistant_id = '9c1c426d-cd33-49ec-a3bc-f0835c3264b5';

    //URL service.
    $url = 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/assistants/';

    //Method for start a new session.
    $method = $assistant_id.'/sessions?version=2019-02-28';

    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(["base_uri" => $url]);

    $response = $client->request('POST', $method, [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization:' => $api_key
        ]
    ]);

    return response;
}
```

Is there any way I can fix this? 
Can you tell me some alternatives to make api call instead of using Guzzle?

Comment: I cannot recommend alternatives. The problem with your code is that you are trying to use an API Key in place of an OAuth Token. This document link will show you how to get the OAuth Token from and API Key. https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/iam?topic=iam-iamtoken_from_apikey This document shows how to do this in CURL: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/watson?topic=watson-iam